# WPF Listbox focus from viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, focus

I've stumbled upon the well-known problem with Listbox and focus. I'm setting `ItemsSource` from the viewmodel and at some point I need to reload them and set selection and focus to a specific item, say:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> items;
private ItemViewModel selectedItem;

private void Process()
{
    items.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        items.Add(new ItemViewModel(i));
    }

    var item = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value == 25);
    SelectedItem = item;
}

public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { /* usual stuff */ }
public ItemViewModel SelectedItem { /* usual stuff */ }
```

Binding may look like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

After calling the method item gets selected, but does not receive focus.

I've read a lot on the Internet and on StackOverflow, but all answers I found involve manual filling of the listbox, not via binding from viewmodel. So the question is: how can I properly focus newly selected item in the presented scenario?

---

To add some context, I'm implementing a sidebar file browser:

[image: Explorer]

I need keyboard navigation on the listbox below treeview.

Comment: I think this could be done with a Behavior attached to the ListBox. Hookup to the SelectedItemChanged-event and manually check/set the focus accordingly. Apart from 'can be done' the queations remains 'should it be done'. If you hit  for example a button to trigger your update, isn't it normal then that any item/ the ListBox looses focus??

Comment: @SanchoPanza, Look at my edits. I've tried that, but then listbox steals focus even if it weren't focused earlier. Upon selecting item in the treeview, I select first element in listbox afterwards. This effectively disallow navigation on the treeview, because listbox immediately becomes focused...

Comment: @SanchoPanza, regarding *should it be done*, scenario is: user chooses ".." and presses Enter; I reload files to show upper folder contents and I'd like to select the folder user was in to improve navigation. Since elements were reloaded, there is none focused and if I didn't set focus on my own, user would end up with first item being focused and selected after pressing the down-arrow key...

Comment: @Spook Have you tried to set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` in `ListBox` xaml?

Comment: @Spook: The `ListBox` must be focused for the item to get highlighted unless you modify the control template for the `ListBoxItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following code in control's codebehind:

```
public void FixListboxFocus()
{
    if (lbFiles.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        lbFiles.ScrollIntoView(lbFiles.SelectedItem);
        lbFiles.UpdateLayout();

        var item = lbFiles.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(viewModel.SelectedFile);
        if (item != null && item is ListBoxItem listBoxItem && !listBoxItem.IsFocused)
            listBoxItem.Focus();
    }
}
```

This method is available for calling from within viewModel, which calls it every time it sets the selection:

```
var file = files.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Path.Equals(subfolderName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
if (file != null)
    SelectedFile = file;
else
    SelectedFile = files.FirstOrDefault();

access.FixListboxFocus();
```

The `access` is view passed to ViewModel via interface (to keep separation between presentation and logic). The relevant XAML part looks like following:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbFiles" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFile}" />
```

Comment: Instead of calling the method from VM, you could have used the SelectionChanged event of the ListBox

Comment: @NawedNabiZada, no, I can't, because this method should be called *only* when selection changes from within viewmodel. Otherwise it ends up with listbox stealing focus every time its selection changes (ie. items being reloaded)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that might work for you:

The control:

```
class FocusableListBox : ListBox
{
    #region Dependency Proeprty

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsFocusedControl", typeof(Boolean), typeof(FocusableListBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsFocusedChanged));

    public Boolean IsFocusedControl
    {
        get { return (Boolean)GetValue(IsFocusedControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsFocusedControlProperty, value); }
    }

    public static void OnIsFocusedChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        ListBox listBox = dependencyObject as ListBox;
        listBox.Focus();
    }

    #endregion Dependency Proeprty
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
 class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Boolean _IsFocused;
    private String selectedItem;

    public ObservableCollection<String> Items { get; private set; }
    public String SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }      

    public Boolean IsFocused
    {
        get { return _IsFocused; }
        set
        {
            _IsFocused = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsFocused");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Process();
    }

    private void Process()
    {
        Items.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        ChangeFocusedElement("2");
    }

    public void ChangeFocusedElement(string newElement)
    {
        var item = Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i == newElement);
        IsFocused = false;
        SelectedItem = item;
        IsFocused = true;
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(String propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<local:FocusableListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            Width="200" 
                            IsFocusedControl="{Binding IsFocused, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The update call:

```
 _viewModel.ChangeFocusedElement("10");
```